# How to filter todays date from a timestamp field?

Tags: filters

We have a field in a data extension with a timestamp value e.g. "2015-04-30 12:46". The data type is text. We would like to filter that column for todays date, preferably using a data filter (sending to that filter at send time). However the condition *equals today* in the preset does not work. Is there a way to solve this without moving to a *query*?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting timestamp as a string right. you can use substring method to seperate the date from the timestamp.

in your case : field.substring(0,10) will retrive the current day in the below format.

2015-04-30